# Mocking public method of testing object

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit, mockery

I have a class that has two public method. It looks something like following:

```php
class IntRequest
{
    public function updateStatus()
    {
        $isValid = $this->checkValidity();

        // ... next is a complex logic that use $isValid
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isValid()
    {
        // another complex logic
    }
}
```

I need to test a first function - `IntRequesr::updateStatus`; however I need to run to tests. The first one with `IntRequests::isValid` returns `false` and the second one with `true` as a result of `IntRequests::isValid`

I try to mock that function but tests run with calling actual `IntRequests::isValid` not mocked one.

My testing code is

```php
$intRequest = new IntRequests;

$mock = m::mock($intRequest);
$mock->shouldReceive('isValid')
    ->once()
    ->andReturn(true);

$res = $mock->updateStatus();

$this->assertTrue($res);
```

I've try to call `$res = $intRequest->updateStatus()` instead of `$res = $mock->updateStatus()` but with no luck.

So, I am wondering is it possible to mock function that is called inside testing method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [partial mock](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/partial_mocks.html) (a mock object, in which some of the methods are stubbed, while the rest are left as is). Since I've done such only with the phpunit's own mock library, I can only point you to the documentation, but it seems that you should just add `->makePartial()` to your mock instantiation